# Javascript: conditional variable initialization in if/else

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I'm initializing a variable conditionally with if/else. I want to follow functional programming rules.

My eg.:

```
  if (1 === 2) {
    const a = false;
  } else {
    const a = true;
  }

  console.log(a);
```

Linter say:  `ESLint: 'a' is not defined.(no-undef).`

As you know there is no way that `a` would not be defined. Another approach could be:

`const a = 1 === 2 ? false : true;`

But what if there were three conditions in if/else? How do I achieve that and avoid error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: so what? this demonstrates that the scope of your 2 const cannot be accessed outside of your if

Comment: @KonradLinkowski probably, so if/else is a block scope and only there I can use a. What's the best solution then with three conditions?

Comment: What are you using this variable for? It would be easier to understand with context.

Comment: Let's say I want to pass it as a function parameter: `doStuff(a);`

Answer (score 1):

That's why I always use `var`. But for your example you can have define `const a` using a function or a intermediate variable.

```js
const a = init_a()

function init_a() {
  if (1 == 2) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}

console.log(a)
```

Comment: var is very old-fashioned speaking  euphemistically

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your variable in a scope that you can access and print.

You can use something more elegant like this:

```
const a = (1 ==2) ? 'A' : 'B'
console.log(a)
```

For more info check [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: I wrote that in question. What if there are three conditions? No, I don't want nested ternary.

Comment: That depends on the situation, you can use object/switch case/break your code into functions so it will be more clean and wont have if and else's in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) if you want to stick to functional programming style.

This is especially useful when dealing with multi-level if and switch statements:

```js
const a = (() => {
    if (1 === 1) {
        return 'first'
    } else if (1 === 2) {
        return 'second'
    } else {
        return 'third'
    }
})()

// 'first'
console.log(a)
```